# WiFi 6 AX200 not connecting Automatically Ubuntu 20.10 after Reboot/Restart

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, intel, iwlwifi

I upgraded my Wireless Card from Intel Wireless 9560 to AX200.
I have Dual Boot Windows OS & Ubuntu 20.10 on my HP Omen.

I updated my wireless driver on my Windows 10 environment.
Everything working perfectly.Every time I boot into my Ubuntu 20.10,
I have to connect to my hidden Wifi every time.

I tried to see if Ubuntu recognizing the AX200 drive.
This is what I found:

```
    krillavilla@krillavilla-OMN:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlw
[sudo] password for krillavilla: 
[    3.259537] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.269345] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.270894] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.270911] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    3.270915] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.270917] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.271217] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.271333] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    3.358293] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.561857] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: e0:d4:e8:53:eb:b1
[    3.577475] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
krillavilla@krillavilla-OMN:~$ lspci -nn | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

**UPDATE**
I went to the Intel website to load the driver using the instruction
provided on this link [Intel Linux Wireless Driverl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)

I still get kicked off my Wifi randomly

***UPDATE***
It's been 4 hours and I did not get kick off my wifi yet.
I did some research and found this article [Kernel Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)
which I already have an updated version of the kernel.

```
krillavilla@krillavilla-OMN:~$ uname -r
5.8.0-28-generic
```

Also, people had reported disabling Fast Boot and secure on Windows 10 OS
[Intel Fast Boot](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Unstable-AX200-connection-in-Ubuntu-20-04/m-p/1205573#M30527). I already disable Fast boot startup and my secure BIOS is disabled since I have Windows OS dual boot.

Now, my issue is my throughput on my Windows 10 OS speed test is over 120mbps download speed. On my Ubuntu 20.10, I get a 55mbps download speed.
All the other devices connected to my TP-Link AX6000 getting over 200+mpbs download speed. my laptop is the only device that getting less than 200mbps.

Why is that?

***UPDATE***

I restart my computer and Ubuntu 20.10 didn't connect to my Wifi automatically. I have to go to Network Manager and connect it manually.

***UPDATE***

Its been several hours and I didn't get kicked off my wifi but I still
have to connect to it manually after restart or reboot.

I have 4 questions I need help with:

1. Can someone help me resolve this error message:

   ```
    [3.484752] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [3.498326] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
   ```
2. Can someone help me figure out why Ubuntu won't connect to my Wifi
   Automatically after reboot/restart?
3. Can anyone explain to me why my Windows 10 OS has way faster Link speed/throughput than my Ubuntu 20.10? Is there a fix for this issue?

4.Is there a way to install WPA 3 and 802.11ax on my Ubuntu laptop?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The message *[3.498326] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -* is not to be worried about at all.
It simply means that it already loaded before the version 55 as you can see in the logs. If you do not want it to show up you can remove the other intel.ucode drivers from /lib/firmware.

The other message means you better update the kernel to a newer linux version.
As a "workaround" (if the error message bothers you), you may set the
iwlwifi module's "enable_ini" parameter to false (e.g., "N"). This
will disable the (attempted) loading of the "iwl-debug-yoyo.bin" file
-- which fails, obviously, causing this error to be generated.

I am afraid the messages have nothing to do with your other problems, like Ubuntu  didn't connect to your Wifi automatically and your internet speed.